# How to add file as Form data in Http request in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-headers, httprequest

I'm writing test cases to a controller in spring boot which takes `MultipartFile` as RequestParam. In the test case method I'm using `TestRestTemplate.exchange()` to send the request to the controller. I'm not sure how to make the Headers correctly so that I can send the request.

The Postman curl looks like this:

curl --location --request POST 'localhost:9091/response/upload' 
--form 'file=@"/home/adityak/Downloads/ClientLog_NEW.txt"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file uploading to any service or endpoint

private String testExchange(File file) {

```
//add file
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
params.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity =
        new HttpEntity<>(params, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
        "/upload-file",
        HttpMethod.POST,
        requestEntity,
        String.class);

HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == HttpStatus.ACCEPTED) {
    result = responseEntity.getBody();
}
return result;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).